# Oracle 12C Audit Trigger On Rename

Tags: oracle, triggers, audit, table-rename

I have an audit trigger used for source control where we track all oracle (12c) object modifications.  How can I get the "new" object name within a rename (whether through "alter" or "rename")?  Regardless if I fire the trigger before or after "ALTER or RENAME or DDL ON DATABASE", I see the "old" name in ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `ORA_SQL_TXT` to catch the triggering statement(via the functions out parameter) and then extract the name of the new object.

edit:
I replaced `ORA_SQL_TEXT` with `ORA_SQL_TXT;`

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to make that work!

if ora_sysevent = 'RENAME' then
 declare
  n PLS_INTEGER;
  sql_text sys.dbms_standard.ora_name_list_t;
 begin
  n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
   v_obj_original := v_obj_original || sql_text(i);
  END LOOP;
 exception
   when others then
  v_obj_original := 'Exception getting DDL:  ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM || ' at ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI');
 end;
end if;